# How to Execute all Javascript of HTML File to produce just HTML DOM using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, dom, render

I have a html file, which doesn't contain almost any HTML elements, because all it have is just many ugly javascripts. But when I open it in browser, all Javascripts are evaluated / executed / rendered (I don't know the best word to use :D ) and I can go to Developer Tools and there I see normal HTML Dom with all elements.

So my question is, is there some kind of library that I can use in .NET 6 in C#, that would do exactly the same as browser is doing, and transform this file full of scripts into normal HTML DOM?

Thank you very much for any help, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: To help your search, the term you're probably looking for is a "headless browser" in C#.  It would essentially be a complete browser engine, just without a UI.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp) - as @David said, you need headless browser. You could also use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/).